# angular js - how to map enum to a color?

Tags: angularjs

I am just getting started on angularjs and have a basic question.
If I have a mapping of log-level to a color - say ERROR is red, WARN is yellow, DEBUG is green and I would like to display the json in html with each enum mapping to a different color, how would I achieve that ?

Here is my json input

```
var jsonString = [
    { "msg" : "this is warning", "level" : WARN },
    { "msg2" : "this is error", "level" : ERROR }
]
```

This is what I would like to be generated

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><th>Message</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="red">this is error</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="yellow">this is warn<td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd just use CSS classes, eg `<td class="error">`, then set the colour in CSS, ie `.error { background-color: red; }`

Comment: I have several places where I need to map an enum and display it on the page (not necessarily color the text) so I prefer the other answer. I haven't tried your approach but I guess it would work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposed solution. However I never heard of that `bgcolor` attribute. If you want to use proper CSS instead, you could replace it by `ng-style="{background-color: colors[message.level]}"`

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = {
    WARN: 'orange',
    ERROR: 'red'
  };
  
  $scope.messages = [
    { "msg" : "this is warning", "level" : "WARN"},
    { "msg" : "this is error",   "level" : "ERROR" }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
    <table>
    <tr><th>Message</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="message in messages">
      <td ng-attr-bgcolor="{{colors[message.level]}}">{{message.msg}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, as suggested by **Phil** in a comment, you could use `ng-class="message.level"` and then add some styling to the `.WARN` and `.ERROR` classes.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. The most important part for me was this syntax **colors[message.level]**

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you have a work in progress but cannot solve something you should try to include the code you've already come up with (well unless it seems too convoluted). Also please accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped you, thanks :-)

Comment: I would love to up-vote but this is my first post :) and I need 15 reputation to do it as I understand. I had a much more complicated example to work with so couldn't come up with a working snippet to post. But will definitely try that for future posts